# How to create an array of custom types typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have an interface with the following:

```
interface orderItem {
  symbol: string,
  side: string,
  price: number
  quantity: number
}
```

I want to create an array "orders" consisting of "orderItems" in my constructor.

However, orders : [orderItem] doesn't seem to be doing the trick. Does anyone know how I can proceed?

Here is what I am trying to do in my constructor:

```
   this.state = {
      orders: orderItem []

  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! I tried what you mentioned but it is saying that "orderItem" is referred to as a type but being used as a value.

Comment: Now that i see you're trying to create an object literal, i've deleted my comment and added a more relevant answer below

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since you're  doing an object literal, the colon is used to divide the key from the value (ie, it has its normal javascript meaning, not its typescript meaning). As a result, trying to set the type the way you're doing is causing an error.

There are a few ways you could do what you want. You could set the type using the `as` keyword:

```
this.state = {
    orders: undefined as orderItem[]
};
```

or with an empty array:

```
this.state = {
    orders: [] as orderItem[]
};
```

Or you could create something ahead of time, and then insert that into the object:

```
let myOrders: orderItem[] = [];
this.state = {
     orders: myOrders
};
```

Or you could have a separate interface for the state and use that:

```
interface myState {
    orders: orderItem[]
}

class myClass {
    private state: myState;
    constructor () {
        this.state = {
            orders: undefined
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Makes a lot more sense now

Answer (score 2):

What you want is this:

```
   this.orders = new Array<orderItem>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare it like this:

```
interface CartState extends Object { orders: OrderItem[] }

class Cart {
  private state: CartState;

  constructor(orders: OrderItem[]) {
    this.state = { orders };
  }
}
```

Typescript [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#array) for declaring arrays.